# Make an API call with variable token with OAuth 2.0

Tags: api, oauth, oauth-2.0, automation, postman

I have faced with a problem. I've never used OAuth 2.0 authentication and now I'm trying to make an API call using OAuth 2.0 Authentication.
Well, I've made a call using Postman, but now I want to automate that. What I mean, I want to get a token in to variable and after an every new call I want to generate new access token.

I have done some things, but still I'm getting a response saying: "Authorization failure".
I've wrote this in collection Pre-requrest Scripts:

```
let tokenUrl = 'tokenUrl';
let clientId = 'clientId';
let clientSecret = 'secret';
let scope = 'scope'

let getTokenRequest = {
    method: 'GET',
    url: tokenUrl,
    auth: {
        type: "basic",
        basic: [
            { key: "username", value: clientId },
            { key: "password", value: clientSecret }
        ]
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'formdata',
        formdata: [
            { key: 'grant_type', value: 'client_credentials' },
            { key: 'scope', value: scope }
        ]
    }
};

pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
    let jsonResponse = response.json(),
        newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;

    console.log({ err, jsonResponse, newAccessToken })

    pm.environment.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
    pm.variables.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
});
```

[image]

After that, when I add a new request and in authorization type i chose inherit auth from parent and trying to send a request, it gives me a response: "Authorization failure"

**P.S:** This is the source website, where I took a script from: https://marcin-chwedczuk.github.io/automatically-generate-new-oauth2-tokens-when-using-postman

Comment: You're setting the accessToken twice, is that just because you copied the code from that tutorial? You can remove the `pm.environment.set()` line as it looks like it's not used and change `variables` to `collectionVariables`. If you set the Auth to 'No Auth' then in the request, manually add an `Authorization` Header with the `{{accessToken}}` value does that work?

Comment: I've made as you said, but the result is same. Here is console log: jsonResponse:
error:"invalid_request"

Comment: When I try to use it on my API call it says: "Authorization failure", but as it is shown in tutorial with the following apis it works correctly.

Comment: You might need to also add `Bearer {{accessToken}}` to the header as that's what the Auth helper would have done.

Comment: How or where should I add this ? I've added in every field Bearer {{accessToken}}, but same result.

Comment: Maybe I need to change auth: {
        type: "basic",
        basic: [
            { key: "username", value: clientId },
            { key: "password", value: clientSecret }
        ]
    }  to oauth2 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved my problem by changing method to POST.
I had an error in the script.
So, new script looks like that:

```
let tokenUrl = 'tokenUrl';
let clientId = 'clientId';
let clientSecret = 'secret';
let scope = 'scope'

let getTokenRequest = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: tokenUrl,
    auth: {
        type: "basic",
        basic: [
            { key: "username", value: clientId },
            { key: "password", value: clientSecret }
        ]
    },
    body: {
        mode: 'formdata',
        formdata: [
            { key: 'grant_type', value: 'client_credentials' },
            { key: 'scope', value: scope }
        ]
    }
};

pm.sendRequest(getTokenRequest, (err, response) => {
    let jsonResponse = response.json(),
        newAccessToken = jsonResponse.access_token;

    console.log({ err, jsonResponse, newAccessToken })

    pm.environment.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
    pm.variables.set('accessToken', newAccessToken);
});
```